# Simple AR Tag classifier

Tags: python, python-2.x, image, opencv

I have been working on creating a simple AR Tag classifier, for detecting a simple AR Tag glyph. Spitting out an image that looks like this:

[image]

With the red circle indicating the corner closest to the orientation square.

My program is structured as follows:

### AR.py (where all the magic happens)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from artag import ARtag


def display_scaled_image(name, image, scale):
    """Function to display a scaled cv2 image
    :param name:
        Window name
    :type name:
        basestring
    :param image:
        Image as numpy array
    :type image:
        numpy.ndarray
    :param scale:
        Scale factor applied to image
    :type scale:
        float
    """
    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    cv2.imshow(name, cv2.resize(image,
            (int(scale * width), int(scale * height)),
            interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC))


def mask_black(img):
    """Function to mask for black boxes in an BGR image
    :param img:
        Numpy image to process
    :type img:
        numpy.ndarray
    :return:
        the masked image
    :rtype:
        numpy.ndarray
    """
    return cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                        cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 511, 10)


def find_tag(img):
    """
    Identify AR tags in an image

    :param img:
        The image to be processed, may be pre-converted to greyscale
    :type img:
        numpy.ndarray
    :return:
        Tuple[List[artag], numpy.ndarray]
    """
    # Convert the image to greyscale if it is not
    if len(img.shape) > 2:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    dims = img.shape[:2]
    # Normalize image size
    img, _ = rescale_img(img)
    kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    img = mask_black(img)
    img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Clean up contours to regular shapes
    culled_conts = []
    for c, h in zip(contours, hierarchy[0]):
        c = cv2.convexHull(c)
        epsilon = 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, epsilon, True)
        culled_conts.append((approx, h))

    img, scale = rescale_img(img, dims)

    # Identify nested shapes as possible AR tags
    ar_tags = []
    for c, h in culled_conts:
        # 4 sided tags
        if len(c) == 4:
            # The tag contains a smaller contour
            if h[2] != -1:
                tag = ARtag(c, culled_conts[h[2]][0], scale)
                if tag.valid():
                    ar_tags.append(tag)

    img = cv2.merge((img, img, img))

    return ar_tags, img


def rescale_img(img, dims=None, width=1024):
    """Rescale image, either to the dimensions provided or to the width
    provided, returning the image and it's dimensions

    :param img:
        The input image
    :type img:
        numpy.ndarray
    :param dims:
        Provide this parameter to fit the image to a specific size
    :type dims:
        Tuple[int, int]
    :param width:
        The width to resize the image to, (overridden by dims) deafualts to 1024
    :type width:
        int
    :return:
        Tuple of image and its dimensions
    :rtype:
        Tuple[numpy.ndarray, Tuple[int, int]]
    """
    grey = img
    if dims is None:
        r = float(width) / grey.shape[1]
        dims = (width, int(grey.shape[0] * r))
    else:
        dims = dims[::-1]
    scale = (dims[1] / float(grey.shape[0]), dims[0] / float(grey.shape[1]))
    return cv2.resize(grey, dims, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA), scale


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Display results for all test images
    import os
    for f in list(os.walk("Test imges"))[0][2]:
        if "jpg" in f:
            in_img = cv2.imread("Test imges/" + f)
            grey = cv2.cvtColor(in_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            ar_tags, proc_img = find_tag(grey)
            for i in ar_tags:
                proc_img = i.draw(proc_img)
                in_img = i.draw(in_img)
            display_scaled_image("Image - {}".format(f), proc_img, .25)
            display_scaled_image("Orig Image - {}".format(f), in_img, .25)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

### artag.py

```
import math

import cv2


class ARtag(object):
    def __init__(self, outer, inner, scale):
        """Create a ARTag object, based on its inner contour,
        outer contour and the scale of the image processed as
        related to the image that was processed to extract them

        :param outer:
            The outer contour (Assumed to have 4 sides)
        :param inner:
            The outer contour (Assumed to have at least 4 sides)
        :param scale:
            The scale of the image that was processed to create this tag
        :type scale:
            Tuple[int, int]
        """
        self.outer_cont = outer
        for i, c in enumerate(self.outer_cont):
            self.outer_cont[i][0][0] = c[0][0] * scale[1]
            self.outer_cont[i][0][1] = c[0][1] * scale[0]
        self.inner_cont = inner
        for i, c in enumerate(self.inner_cont):
            self.inner_cont[i][0][0] = c[0][0] * scale[1]
            self.inner_cont[i][0][1] = c[0][1] * scale[0]

        self.outer_tup = [tuple(i[0]) for i in outer]
        self.inner_tup = [tuple(i[0]) for i in inner]

        x, y = zip(*self.inner_tup)
        x = sum(x) / len(x)
        y = sum(y) / len(y)

        self.outer_tup = sorted(self.outer_tup, key=lambda p: math.sqrt((p[0] - x)**2 + (p[1] - y)**2))

        # Points of interest labeled clockwise from marked corner
        self.p0 = self.outer_tup[0]
        self.p1 = self.outer_tup[1]
        self.p2 = self.outer_tup[3]
        # Furthest point must be the 3rd point
        self.p3 = self.outer_tup[2]

    def draw(self, img):
        """Draw the tag on a 3 channel image

        :param img:
            The 3 channel image
        :type img:
            numpy.ndarray
        :return:
            The input image
        :rtype:
            numpy.ndarray
        """
        img = cv2.drawContours(img, [self.outer_cont], -1, (0, 255, 0), 10)
        img = cv2.drawContours(img, [self.inner_cont], -1, (255, 0, 0), 10)
        img = cv2.circle(img, tuple(self.p0), 20, (0, 0, 255), 10)
        return img

    def ratio(self, img):
        """Ratio of the size of the Tag vs the input image size

        :param img:
            The input image
        :type img:
            numpy.ndarray
        :return:
            The processed image
        :rtype:
            numpy.ndarray
        """
        return cv2.contourArea(self.outer_cont) / float(img.shape[0] * img.shape[1])

    def in_outer(self):
        return cv2.contourArea(self.inner_cont) / cv2.contourArea(self.outer_cont)

    @staticmethod
    def dist(p0, p1):
        """ Return the distance between two tuples in the format (x, y)

        :param p0:
            The first point
        :type p0:
            Tuple[int, int]
        :param p1:
            The second point
        :type p1:
            Tuple[int, int]
        :return:
            The distance
        :rtype:
            float
        """
        return math.sqrt((p0[0] - p1[0])**2 + (p0[1] - p1[1])**2)

    def valid(self):
        """Check the validity of this artag
        Check the following items:
         - Any line distance is more than 1.8 times the average length
         - Any line distance is less than .2 times the average length
         - The inner contour takes up more than 10% of the tag
         - The inner contour takes up less than 1% of the tag

        :return:
            The validity of the tag
        :rtype:
            bool
        """
        lengths = [
            self.dist(self.p0, self.p1),
            self.dist(self.p1, self.p2),
            self.dist(self.p2, self.p3),
            self.dist(self.p3, self.p0)
        ]
        # check aspect ratio
        if any([i > 1.8 * sum(lengths) / len(lengths) for i in lengths]):
            return False
        if any([i < .2 * sum(lengths) / len(lengths) for i in lengths]):
            return False
        # Check area ratios
        if cv2.contourArea(self.inner_cont) / cv2.contourArea(self.outer_cont) > 0.1:
            return False
        if cv2.contourArea(self.inner_cont) / cv2.contourArea(self.outer_cont) < 0.01:
            return False
        return True
```

It seems to work great, except for image 11 seems to fail to detect the Tag, this has somthing to do with the [nesting of the contours](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html). What I would like to do to fix this image, would be to do somthing like find large 4-sided contours that have smaller 4 sided contours inside, that are not nested and have 4 sides.

The problem is the structure of the hierarchy object returned by opencv. It has the indexes of the contours, but if you modify the list it makes this useless. I would love to have a data structure for the contours, that have the data baked in, but the problem occurs if I start removing contours, becouse they are invalid or somthing I get problems referring to contours that are nonexistent.

Any input on solving this problem elegantly would be a great in addition to a general review of the code.

#### My code is hosted on github here: [AR-Testing](https://github.com/ferret-guy/AR-Testing)

#### You can download all the code with the test images here: [AR-Testing.zip](https://codeload.github.com/ferret-guy/AR-Testing/zip/1379a363cda73d83f46415c7600a63fe7ee98eaf)